# Dual channel RAM for laptop

Tags: memory, dual-channel

I need to upgrade my laptop's RAM to 8GB.It has a dual channel configuration as below:

hynix 4GB PC3L-12800 CL:11

hynix 2GB PC3L-12800 CL:11

Now i want to replace the 2GB RAM with a 4GB RAM.Specs as below:

Ramaxel 4GB PC3L-12800 CL:11

As specified above,they are the same.But,the tRCD numbers are different.(one of them 12 and 13 for another).

Does it cause problems like mismatch or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your laptop isn't currently using dual channel - it's only possible with identical capacities.

When RAM modules have different timings, underclocking will be applied to make them match. It should work fine.